# Criptografia de dados mysql

Tags: mysql

Alguém pode me ajudar,
Estou usando AES_ENCRYPT(string,string_chave) ([manual](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/miscellaneous-functions.html)) para fazer criptográfica com chave.

```html
Veja minha sintax. INSERT INTO trava (codigoliberacao) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('123456789', 'Chave'));
```

***ou seja. insert into tabela (campo)values(AES_ENCRYPT('Valor', 'Chave'));***

A msg do mysql responde (1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)).

Mas na consulta normal, não aparece a criptografia, ou seja é como se o campo tive ficado em branco. Veja as imagem[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E qual foi o *warning* que ele deu?

Comment: (1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s))
Execution Time : 00:00:00:140
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:140

Comment: @Fabrício, poste o script de criação da sua tabela também, por gentileza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES_ENCRYPT() criptografa uma string com uma chave e retorna uma string binária contendo a saída criptografada que deve ser armazenado em um campo para dados binários como *BLOB*.
Para visualizar um campo *BLOB* você deve fazer um cast para string, isso pode ser feito assim (no caso de alguns editores SQL isso é feito automaticamente, o MySQL Workbench, por exemplo, não faz, já o SQLyog sim):

```
SELECT CAST(codigoliberacao AS CHAR(50)) AS codigoliberacao_string
FROM trava;
```

Assim, você pode ver os dados mas, criptografado. Mas, se quiser obtê-lo sem criptpgrafia pode usar a função AES_DECRYPT(), por exemplo:

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(codigoliberacao, 'chave') AS CHAR(50)) codigoliberacao_sem_criptografia 
FROM trava;
```

Comment: E como eu faço para fazer o comando inert? Esse é meu verdadeiro ploblema

INSERT INTO trava (codigoliberacao)
VALUES(aes_encrypt('22334455667788','qewretayhsgcvbdjfkrotit'));

Comment: A sintaxe está correta, mas o dado está sendo armazenado em que tipo de dados?

Comment: blz amidgo luide, troquei o tipode dados blob e de Deu Certo. Muito obrigado

Comment: De nada. Estamos aqui para ajudar uns aos outros. :)